# SignInStatus always returns Success on TwoFactorAuthentication is enabled in webapi using asp.net identity

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, owin

I am implementing 2 factor authentication in WebApi, asp.net identity and OWIN. Every time I log in, I get SignInStatus = Success never reaches to SignInStatus = RequiresVerification though user TwoFactorAuthentication is enabled.

Below are some code snippets, 
Startup.cs:

```
private void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
            app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
            app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
            app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);

            app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);
        }


Action method for enabling two factor authentication,
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> EnableTwoFactorAuthentication()
        {
            var user = await this.AppUserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());
            if (user != null)
            {
                IdentityResult result = await this.AppUserManager.SetTwoFactorEnabledAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId(), true);

                await this.AppSignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);

                if (!result.Succeeded)
                {
                    return GetErrorResult(result);
                }
            }
            return Ok();
        }
```

Please suggest a solution.

Comment: Issue resolved! I missed to register two factor authentication providers in application user manager.

Below is code snippet,
appUserManager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Phone Code", new PhoneNumberTokenProvider<IdentityUser>
            {
                MessageFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
            });
            appUserManager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Email Code", new EmailTokenProvider<IdentityUser>
            {
                Subject = "Security Code",
                BodyFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
            });

Now getting correct SignInStatus.

Answer (score 1):

If you get stuck here, one way to solve the problem is to copy the methods from [SignInManager](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetIdentity/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin/SignInManager.cs) directly into your code and call those instead so you can step through the methods and see why you are getting the wrong status. For me the problem ended up being that I instantiated my `UserManager` with:

```
new MyUserManager()
```

instead of the right way:

```
HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<MyUserManager>()
```

I was using this as my template for setting it up:
https://github.com/adamtuliper/ASP.NET-Identity-Samples/tree/master/BasicTemplate%20-%20Two%20Factor/BasicTemplate

Answer (score 1):

SignInManager return RequiresVerification if :

dbo.ASpnetUsers has for user set to true TwoFactorEnabled and EmailConfirmed and user email should be confirmed, email not be empty or null.

```
var result = SignInManager.PasswordSignIn(usernameIdentity, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: true);

switch (result)
 {
     case SignInStatus.Success:
         return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
     case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
         return RedirectToAction("SendCode", returnUrl);
     case SignInStatus.Failure:
     default:
         ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username or password.");
         return View(model);
 }
```